# How does Lua check conditions in an IF statement?

Tags: if-statement, optimization, lua

I am trying to optimize my IF statement in Lua. When there are two conditions in an IF statement with the AND operator, does Lua read left to right and stop as soon as it reaches one false? That is, if there is a condition which is quick to check and a condition which is slower to check, is it more efficient to put the condition which is quick to check first (i.e. left most)?

For example, assume I have two functions that return true or false, quick_fn() and slow_fn(), and I want to execute code only if both functions return true. In terms of speed, is there a difference between the following two ways of writing this code? If Option #1 is equivalent, should I always be putting the quick_fn() in the leftmost spot?

Option #1:

```
if quick_fn() AND slow_fn() then 
  [code]
end
```

Option #2:

```
if quick_fn() then
  if slow_fun() then
    [code]
  end
end
```

Comment: There is no `AND` in Lua. It's spelled `and`.

Comment: It seems it would have been easiest just to write out `quick_fn()` returning false and `slow_fn()` and then running the code to see if both get called.

Comment: @larsks If Lua semantics were such that the operation may or may not short-circuit, then trying it wouldn't necessarily tell you anything. It's easiest to check the language definition. (`and` and `or` always short-circuit.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [Lua documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.5) (emphasis added):

> The negation operator **`not`** always returns **`false`** or **`true`**. The
> conjunction operator **`and`** returns its first argument if this value is
> **`false`** or **`nil`**; otherwise, and returns its second argument. The
> disjunction operator or returns its first argument if this value is
> different from **`nil`** and **`false`**; otherwise, or returns its second
> argument. *Both **`and`** and **`or`** use short-circuit evaluation; that is, the
> second operand is evaluated only if necessary.*

Note that the operator is spelled `and`, not `AND`. Lua is case-sensitive.